What is the distribution of sampled variance from a finite population?
Suppose there are certain sample mean x and sampled standard deviation sigma given N,  then n number of data is sampled from this finite sample without replacement .
The variance of the resampled means can be found by using the finite correction factor ,and the  standardized score follow either t or z distribution depending whether the sigma is known.
It is clear that the distribution of sampled variance follows a chi square distribution when sampling with replacement.
But, the important question is "what is the distribution of the sampled variance from a fixed sample (finite population) without replacement? "
For example, suppose there are sampled mean = 10, and sigma = 2 with N= 20. n = 10 is randomly selected from the finite population of 20 without replacement, what is the distribution of re-sampled variance ? ( note, I am not asking the variance of re-sampled means, which can be found using the fcf)
